# using pipenv with git submodules

Tags: python, django, git-submodules, pipenv

I have a git submodule B, that works as an app in my django project A. B has its own Pipfile and Pifile.lock. A also has a Pipfile and Pipfile.lock. How can I use pipenv, to install the libraries  from both pipfiles within the same virtuaelenv?

Answer (score 2):

go to the directory where each pipfile exist and run `pipenv install`. Make sure your virtualenv is activated.